# How to retrieve answers from firestore for a quiz app when we store questions and answers is separate collections?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I read on multiple stack overflow posts that we should'nt store questions and answers in Firestore for a quiz app in the same documents. So I created two collections, one represent the questions the other the answers. Here is my firestore architecture:

[image: Question architecture image one]
[image: Question architecture image two]
[image: Answer architecture image one]
[image: Answer architecture image two]

When the user clicks on a category the application get 10 questions of a category after the user can click on one answer for each questions. **My problem is how to compare properly the answer the user clicks on with the good answer? I do not want the user to hack my game and know each good answer of all questions.**
I see two options:

- When the user clicks on an answer, my app send a query to firestore to retrieve the good answer of the question and once the data is loaded it compares with the answer that the users clicked on. I fear this solution because the user needs to wait the data loads when he clicks on the answer.
- The second solution I see is to get all the 10 questions and good answers at the beginning of the game and store all goods answers in a list and retrieve the good answer with the question index. I don't know if the user can hack my app to see all good answers but he will not waits to get the result of his/her choice.

Comment: this is not up to mark architecture

Answer (score 1):

use like this
collection name->document name(u can also put document name
as question name) ->in document field you can store the value like picture show[image]

rt means right answer in this question right answer is option b .